# Meshroom in Google Colab but no output file

Tags: google-colaboratory, meshroom

I tried using meshroom to make a 3d model using google colab. Everything worked fine but there was no output file. I tried mounting mega instead of google drive, but no luck. Instead, I got the following text(some of output cut due to word limit). This is the colab notebook that I used: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10T2pDZGRUd5r1UiAvQUwJZTqE_tLydcu

```
[12:26:49.520867][info] Bundle Adjustment Statistics:
    - local strategy enabled: no
    - adjustment duration: 0.00275099 s
    - poses:
        - # refined:  2
        - # constant: 0
        - # ignored:  0
    - landmarks:
        - # refined:  88
        - # constant: 0
        - # ignored:  0
    - intrinsics:
        - # refined:  0
        - # constant: 1
        - # ignored:  0
    - # residual blocks: 176
    - # successful iterations: 12
    - # unsuccessful iterations: 0
    - initial RMSE: 0.386763
    - final   RMSE: 0.36501
[12:26:49.520935][info] Remove outliers: 
    - # outliers residual error: 0
    - # outliers angular error: 0
[12:26:49.520954][info] Bundle adjustment iteration: 0 took 3 msec.
[12:26:49.520966][info] Bundle adjustment with 1 iterations took 3 msec.
[12:26:49.521135][info] Initial pair is: 738871193, 833403405
[12:26:49.521201][info] Begin Incremental Reconstruction:
    - mode: SfM augmentation
    - # images in input: 236
    - # images in resection: 234
    - # landmarks in input: 44
    - # cameras already calibrated: 2
[12:26:49.521225][info] Incremental Reconstruction start iteration 0:
    - # number of resection groups: 0
    - # number of poses: 2
    - # number of landmarks: 44
    - # remaining images: 234
[12:26:49.522265][info] Update Reconstruction:
    - resection id: 0
    - # images in the resection group: 1
    - # images remaining: 234
[12:26:49.522355][info] [3/236] Robust Resection of view: 18451152
[12:26:49.529856][info] Robust Resection information:
    - resection status: true
    - threshold (error max): 2.89881
    - # points used for resection: 32
    - # points validated by robust resection: 31
[12:26:49.532694][info] Bundle adjustment start.
[12:26:49.532746][info] Start bundle adjustment iteration: 0
block_sparse_matrix.cc:81 Allocating values array with 15600 bytes.
detect_structure.cc:95 Dynamic f block size because the block size changed from 6 to 4
detect_structure.cc:113 Schur complement static structure <2,3,-1>.
detect_structure.cc:95 Dynamic f block size because the block size changed from 6 to 4
detect_structure.cc:113 Schur complement static structure <2,3,-1>.
[12:26:49.552254][info] Bundle Adjustment Statistics:
    - local strategy enabled: no
    - adjustment duration: 0.0190014 s
    - poses:
        - # refined:  3
        - # constant: 0
        - # ignored:  0
    - landmarks:
        - # refined:  75
        - # constant: 0
        - # ignored:  0
    - intrinsics:
        - # refined:  1
        - # constant: 0
        - # ignored:  0
    - # residual blocks: 150
    - # successful iterations: 51
    - # unsuccessful iterations: 0
    - initial RMSE: 0.476511
    - final   RMSE: 0.313505
[12:26:49.552361][info] Remove outliers: 
    - # outliers residual error: 0
    - # outliers angular error: 0
[12:26:49.552432][info] Bundle adjustment iteration: 0 took 19 msec.
[12:26:49.552454][info] Bundle adjustment with 1 iterations took 19 msec.
[12:26:49.625419][info] Incremental Reconstruction start iteration 1:
    - # number of resection groups: 1
    - # number of poses: 0
    - # number of landmarks: 0
    - # remaining images: 233
[12:26:49.625465][info] Incremental Reconstruction completed with 2 iterations:
    - # number of resection groups: 1
    - # number of poses: 0
    - # number of landmarks: 0
    - # remaining images: 233
[12:26:49.625540][info] Structure from Motion statistics:
    - # input images: 236
    - # cameras calibrated: 0
    - # poses: 0
    - # landmarks: 0
    - elapsed time: 0.104
    - residual RMSE: -nan
[12:26:49.625566][info] Histogram of residuals:

0   |   0
0.1 |   0
0.2 |   0
0.3 |   0
0.4 |   0
0.5 |   0
0.6 |   0
0.7 |   0
0.8 |   0
0.9 |   0
1

[12:26:49.625587][info] Histogram of observations length:

0   |   0
0.1 |   0
0.2 |   0
0.3 |   0
0.4 |   0
0.5 |   0
0.6 |   0
0.7 |   0
0.8 |   0
0.9 |   0
1

[12:26:49.625605][info] Histogram of nb landmarks per view:

0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
0   |   0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this part of the code?

```
# Choose format (tar.gz or zip)
!tar -czvf out.tar.gz ./out
from google.colab import files

files.download('out.tar.gz')
```

---

```
!zip -r out.zip ./out
files.download('out.zip')
```

For more information you can check this source:
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/natowi/3044484ad0c98877692c399297e3ab7e/meshroomcolab.ipynb#scrollTo=VQ8F_rxPw4dK